# Using jOOQ with Google Cloud SQL

Tags: java, sql, google-app-engine, jooq

I want to know how to use [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/) with Google Cloud SQL. The link provided in the guide seems to be broken:

https://github.com/lukaseder/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ-google-cloud-sql/src/org/jooq/test/JOOQTest.java

Is it still supported, or there were changes in the Cloud SQL that jOOQ cannot run on it anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you have found that link on [this blog post here](http://blog.jooq.org/2011/10/22/jooq-and-google-cloud-sql-example/). That was a proof of concept of using jOOQ as a dependency in a Google App Engine project. It worked nicely, but the integration is currently not maintained.

The main changes in Cloud SQL were changes in licensing terms for us as the [jOOQ vendor](http://www.datageekery.com). If you'd like formal support for this platform, I'm sure that some agreement can be made.

Comment: Actually I am just trying jOOQ for open source projects. To see the feasibility of it being used in a GAE environment, and BTW, GAE is not just Google anymore, JBoss have its App Engine platform CapeDwaft + Openshift, also there is AppScale

Comment: Sure, no worries. I'm positive it'll work decently if you just use the MySQL dialect in jOOQ. Of course, any feedback about your integration experience is very helpful on the [user group](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/jooq-user)

Comment: Actually, I am also curious if jOOQ can work with GAE Datastore, using a debugging I can see that the datastore Query object looks like this: q={com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query@2185}"SELECT * FROM friends WHERE age >= 25" do you think this makes sense?

Comment: Our general take on these SQLesque query languages is that we do not want to support them. Abstracting [the relatively primitive GQL](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference) with jOOQ would make for a very leaky abstraction. Maybe, you could have the [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com) guys implement such a backend?

Comment: I mean, if there's a SQL driver for Google App Engine datastore, would it be supported by jOOQ?

Comment: I though it's just MySQL? The Google App Engine datastore is not *officially* supported, but we've seen people who got it to work with the MySQL dialect...